# Chapel: Array of arrays vs 2-dim array on memory

Tags: arrays, chapel

In Chapel, it seems possible to declare an array by using the notation `[][]`. This looks very similar to "array of arrays" in other languages, so I am wondering whether it is a so-called "jagged array" with each sub-array allocated independently in memory? For example, in the following code, are `a[0][..]` and `a[1][..]` not necessarily contiguous in memory?
(My interest here is whether the use of such `[][]` may be less efficient than `[,]` because of non-contiguous memory.)

```
proc test( D1, D2 )
{
    var a: [D1][D2] int;   // "jagged" array?
    var b: [D1, D2] int;   // I assume this is a rectanguar (contiguous) array

    for i in D1 do
    for j in D2 do
        a[i][j] = i * 100 + j;

    for (i, j) in b.domain do
        b[i, j] = i * 100 + j;

    var lo = D1.low, hi = D1.high;

    writeln( "a = ", a );
    writeln( "a[ lo ] = ", a[ lo ] );
    writeln( "a[ hi ] = ", a[ hi ] );
    writeln();
    writeln( "b = ", b );
    writeln( "b[ lo, .. ] = ", b[ lo, .. ] );
    writeln( "b[ hi, .. ] = ", b[ hi, .. ] );
}

test( 0..1, 1..3 );

$ chpl test.chpl
$ ./a.out

a = 1 2 3 101 102 103
a[ lo ] = 1 2 3
a[ hi ] = 101 102 103

b = 1 2 3
101 102 103
b[ lo, .. ] = 1 2 3
b[ hi, .. ] = 101 102 103
```

A related question is: Is there any way or command to know the memory location (address) of a given variable or array element (to get information on memory allocation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that for an array of arrays in Chapel (`var A: […][…] …`) each of the sub-arrays will be stored independently and therefore may not be contiguous in memory (though they may be, depending on where the allocator places them).  Whether or not they are contiguous, there is an extra indirection required to get to the sub-arrays.

The implementation of a multidimensional array (`var A: […, …] …`) is governed by its domain map which controls how the elements are stored in memory.  The default domain map stores multidimensional arrays contiguously in memory.

Which array form is more efficient will likely depend on the style of computation you write and the system on which you are running.  But, as a specific example, if you were to access the array's elements serially, the multidimensional array would typically outperform the array-of-arrays due to its contiguous memory locations, as you note.

Chapel proper does not like to expose addresses much, but if you lean on some of the interoperability features, you can determine where things live.  For example, the following program uses `c_ptrTo()` in order to get a C pointer to some array elements and then `printf()` to print those locations out:

```
use CPtr;

config const n = 3;

var A: [1..n][1..n] real;

var a11 = c_ptrTo(A[1][1]),
    a12 = c_ptrTo(A[1][2]),
    a21 = c_ptrTo(A[2][1]);

var B: [1..n, 1..n] real;

var b11 = c_ptrTo(B[1,1]),
    b12 = c_ptrTo(B[1,2]),
    b21 = c_ptrTo(B[2,1]);

extern proc printf(x...);

printf("%p %p %p\n", a11, a12, a21);
printf("%p %p %p\n", b11, b12, b21);
```

Comment: W.r.t. "though they may be, depending on where the allocator places them":  When I ran the program above with n == 2 (or other powers of two that I tried), my allocator made the two sub-arrays contiguous in memory, leading to some mild panic on my part.  For n == 3, I got discontiguous addresses.  Of course, your mileage may vary.

Comment: W.r.t. "jagged arrays": While Chapel was designed such that arrays-of-arrays could be used for "jagged"/"skyline" arrays (ones in which the subarrays have different sizes), the current implementation only supports cases in which the inner arrays all share the same domain (index set).  This means that in practice such arrays will still be (virtually) rectangular at present.  The typical workaround for representing a truly jagged array is to store an array of objects where each stores its own domain/array fields---this permits the different sub-arrays to have different sizes.

Comment: Thanks very much! Because I have seen some example codes where tuples like (real, real, real) was used together with arrays (e.g., var A: [1..n] 3*real), I was wondering if we could do the same thing as "var A: [1..n][1..3] real;" because this is closer to other languages. But here, although tuples are of value type so they are probably contiguous in A, I was not sure if [1..n][1..3] gives a contiguous array. So, the speed might be a bit lower than "[1..n] 3*real" also.. I will try comparing these later.

Comment: You are correct that in many respects `var A: [1..n] 3*real;` and `var A: [1..n] [1..3] real;` are fairly equivalent. Our current implementation code-generates tuples as static C arrays in the back-end, so the tuple elements case will end up in contiguous memory as you guess. A Chapel compiler could potentially optimize the "array of small, statically-sized arrays" case to use the same layout, but ours doesn't today. As an example of a difference between the two, if `A[i]` were passed to a routine that expected arrays and did things like query its domain, that wouldn't work for the tuple case.